# Delete blank pages from PDF does not work

Tags: linux, debian, shell, pdf, script

I would like to use this script from this thread: [Remove blank pages from PDF from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1248528/remove-blank-pages-from-pdf-from-command-line).

```
#!/bin/sh
IN="$1"
filename=$(basename "${IN}")
filename="${filename%.*}"
PAGES=$(pdfinfo "$IN" | grep ^Pages: | tr -dc '0-9')

non_blank() {
    for i in $(seq 1 $PAGES)
    do
        PERCENT=$(gs -o -  -dFirstPage=${i} -dLastPage=${i} -sDEVICE=inkcov "$IN" | grep CMYK | nawk 'BEGIN { sum=0; } {sum += $1 + $2 + $3 + $4;} END { printf "%.5f\n", sum } ')
        if [ $(echo "$PERCENT > 0.001" | bc) -eq 1 ]
        then
            echo $i
            #echo $i 1>&2
        fi
        echo -n . 1>&2
    done | tee "$filename.tmp"
    echo 1>&2
}

set +x
pdftk "${IN}" cat $(non_blank) output "${filename}.pdf"
```

The first thing is that I get several syntax errors like

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
./delete2.sh: 11: [: -eq: unexpected operator
.(standard_in) 1: syntax error
./delete2.sh: 11: [: -eq: unexpected operator
.(standard_in) 1: syntax error
./delete2.sh: 11: [: -eq: unexpected operator
.(standard_in) 1: syntax error
./delete2.sh: 11: [: -eq: unexpected operator
.
```

I could fix this errors with additional brackets and and quotation marks but the result is that the output pdf is exactly the same as the input pdf. The blank pages are not removed. Furthermore with the additional brackets and quotation marks I get a file in the output folder that is called "0.001" which is the value next to $PERCENT in the code:

> if [ $(echo "$PERCENT > 0.001" | bc) -eq 1 ]

When I use

> gs -o out.tmp -sDEVICE=inkcov my.pdf

in the terminal I get reproducible results for the pages in the PDF file.

Can anyone help me how to fix this code that it works properly on my Raspberry Pi 3 with Debian bullseye?

By the way: I tested the script on my chromebook with debian bullseye and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

This made it working